# Java - Is ObjectInput/OutputStream compatible with DataInput/OutputStream?

Tags: java, stream

For example:

- I send a byte[] over Socket outputStream using ObjectInput/OutputStream:

  ```
  ObjectOutputStream myOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(mySocket.getOutputStream());
  myOutput.write(myByteArray);
  ```
- At the other end, he use DataInputStream (and may use other InputStream as well) to read:

  ```
  DataInputStream hisInput = new DataInputStream(hisSocket.getInputStream());
  hisInput.read(hisByteArray);
  ```

So my question is:

- Will the receiver read the byte[] correctly?
- What about String using writeObject and readUTF?

Info:

- I can only use Java library (JRE8) and is new to Java's Stream.
- I can not expect or force the other side to use what Stream other than knowing that they are not using ObjectInput/OutputStream
- I asked this question because using ObjectInput/OutputStream MAY save me some work, I took advice from my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26531480/java-how-to-send-efficiently-binary-data-between-string-over-socket).

Comment: Just FYI, both the Data and Object Input/Output streams date back to an age when communication/serialization protocols were not nearly as well developed as they are now. These days we have XML and JSON, both of which are technology neutral and big / little endian neutral.

Comment: Is it a `Byte[]` or a `byte[]`?

Comment: @DavidConrad  Oh! I'm sorry, typo, I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will the receiver read the Byte[] correctly?

No.

> What about String using writeObject and readUTF?

No.

If you use `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject` to write, the only *practical* way to read the stream is using `ObjectOutputStream.readObject`.

In theory, you could write code to implement the [serialization protocol](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html) yourself (using byte or "data" input streams), but it is not a sensible / practical approach.

---

> I can not expect or force the other side to use what Stream other than knowing that they are not using ObjectInput/OutputStream

Whatever you use as the format when you write, you will be forcing the other end to use something that is capable of reading it.  Forcing the other end (if it is Java) to use ObjectInputStream should not be a concern.  It is another matter if the other end could be implemented in another language, but then you should probably be considering something like JSON or XML as your encoding scheme.

Comment: That's a harsh fact, so in short, ObjectOutputStream can only work with ObjectInputStream????

Comment: I didn't say that.  I said it is the only **practical** way.  You could implement code that unpicked the Java object serialization format (it is specified!) ... but that is hardly a practical solution.

Comment: Java Serialize primitive type too? I thought because it is primitive, it doesn't have to be Serialized.

Comment: A `Byte[]` is not primitive.

Comment: @DavidConrad Well, it's related to my other question about forcing or not. But I've edited my question, sorry for my typo, it's actually byte[] not Byte[].

Comment: A `byte[]` is still not primitive, even though a `byte` is; an array is an object.

Comment: @DavidConrad Oh! Thank you! The ObjectStream plan failed then. Is there another stream that has neat method like writeObject and readObject of ObjectStream?

Comment: No, but any OutputStream can write a byte[].

Comment: @DavidConrad Actually, I liked ObjectStream because it can write and read a whole object, other Stream is too primitive so there is bug when I send String mix with Byte[]

Comment: @Tr1et Okay, write it out with ObjectOutputStream and read it in with ObjectInputStream.